# Compare the date if the columns (day, month and year) are stored separately in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns `Day`, `Month` and `Year` of type `INT` that are totally separate. What I need is to pass a date (format: `yyyy-mm-dd`) into a `WHERE` clause to check if this following date is matched or not. What would be the best approach to handle this issue?

Comment: Fix the database to use an *appropriate data type*? I'd love to see the check constraint that *validates* these fields and ensures you don't get nonsense stored in them.

Comment: Can you change the DDL of the table? personally I would suggest adding a `PERSISTED` computed column, adding (it to) an index and querying that. Anything else is doing to likely to perform poorly. Unfortunately, as you're using SQL Server 2008, you don't have access to `TRY_CONVERT`, so if you have bad data, you could have some problems.

Comment: How do you make sure no invalid dates are stored into these 3 seperate columns ?

Comment: I'm actually a little disappointed the OP hasn't told us how they are validating their data. I'm actually quite interested to see the solution.

Comment: @Larnu Yes im too am very curious about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2012 it would be `DateFromParts(Year,Month,Day)`, but you have tagged 2008 which means we have to fall back to the older tricks.

```
dateadd(mm, (@YourYearValue - 1900) * 12 + @YourMonthValue- 1 , @YourDayValue - 1)
```

Put your 3 ints into that (via columns from a join or parameters as appropriate) and you have a date returned you can work with.

SQL Fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/19988

Comment: Please check the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/151f3/4 your query shows the table scan instead.

Answer (score 0):

*For SQL Server 2008*

```
    declare @Day int = 29, @Month int = 5, @Year int = 2018

    select t.*
    from [table] t
    where t.[Date] = cast(cast(@Year as char(4))+ '-' + cast(@Month as char(2)) + '-' + cast(@Day as char(2)) as date)
```

*Only for 2012 and later* use DATEFROMPARTS:

```
where t.[Date] = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, @Day)
```

Comment: The OP tagged they are using SQL Server 2008.  This isn't much use to them as a result.

Comment: @Larnu I jumped the gun so added a 2008 compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution:

```
where cast(cast(@yyyy as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(@mm as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(@dd as 
varchar(2)) as date) ...
```

and replace @yyyy,@mm,@dd with your fields

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following, Instead of making a date using separated values we can take part from the complete date using SQL functions and compare with accordingly, which I think the best way of comparison

```
DECLARE @Day INT=29, @Month INT=05, @Year INT = 2018, 
    @Date DATE = '2018-05-29'
SELECT * FROM yourTable 
WHERE YEAR(@Date) = @Year
AND MONTH(@Date) = @Month
AND DAY(@Date) = @Day
```

Comment: Will this get index support?

Comment: Definitely it will ! don't you think so ?

Comment: @Susang It definitely doesn't. It is not sargable.

Comment: No, I'm not convinced it will - a quick test shows a table scan : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63625/2 - using the dateadd technique shows an index seek : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63625/3

Comment: Sorry for saying that but you guys took it to the wrong direction because Day, Month and Year are the table columns and pass a date (format: yyyy-mm-dd) is parameter so we index on Day, Month and Year and works exactly what you all not expected. Please check (Index Seek) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/151f3/4

Comment: @Susang - actually re-reading the question, I'd agree they might mean its this way around - although that then makes this a very simple question / answer, perhaps too simple.

Comment: @Andrew That means you answered without reading the question properly so that you `re-read` it. You look very experienced so it's obvious not expecting it along with comments thrown above from you. So you don't think my answer is more simpler than yours and elegant in every aspects ?

Comment: @Susang - I merely concurred that the question could mean either way around. Depending on how you interpret it, then one solution or the other has no index support - and I was not alone in reading it that way. I'll leave the voting to determine what is deemed the right way and elegant. If you really need to continue the conversation, please find me on chat.